# Content Type Delete and Republish

Tags: 2010, content-type-hub

So i published a content type from my hub but deleted it from one of the consuming sites. Now when i try to republish it again, i'm not able to bring it up at the site. Am i missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wish this forum would be more active.

Anyway, I only had to wait until the Content Type Hub and Content Type Subscriber timer jobs to complete and then they were visible.